# Can not access a variable inside another function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript so I am sorry if I am asking some easy questions.

The problem I am encountering is that I want to access the variable **point** inside the function **UpdateChart**, but I receive nothing. If I would move the alert line below ws.onmessage function, I would recieve the value. So how can I receive the value point inside the updateChart function?

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {

    // Responsible for splitting the array. 
    var point = evt.data.split(",");

    var updateChart = function(count) {
        alert(point); // <--                    I receive nothing :(  
    }

}
```

Comment: The code you posted contains no calls to the function "updateChart", so of course the `alert()` doesn't run.

Comment: Your alert is inside a function which is never, as far as your code shows, called.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the function does not call it, you need to call it for it to do something:

```
...
var updateChart = function(count) {
    alert(point); 
}
updateChart(point);
...
```